# 'Unresolved reference...' errors for import a kotlin file from another module in android

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture

I have problems when i import a kotlin class from another module, but there is no problem with Java class . I configed kotlin in my project. Below is my 'data' module library, and i want to import Kotlin classes from 'domain' module.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
...
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation project(':domain')
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71'
  ...
}
```

When I build the project, it´s giving me lot of error messages 'Unresolved reference: ...' . But the IDE itself doesn´t have a problem. The errors will disappear if i remove all kotlin importing and their object.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since the IDE behavior differs from that of the Gradle build, you can report this as a potential issue to the [Kotlin issue tracker](https://kotl.in/issue). If your project is an open-source one, it would be great if you shared it as well. Otherwise, more details about the project structure or a minimal sample project that shows the same problem would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I missed something in 'domain' library 
Here is my resolve : (add these code in 'domain' library )

```
    // thieu 2 cai lol ni se bi loi ko the import kotlin file
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 2):

For me I am adding:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

to the module. And after that it works.